# Xperia album widget stackview implementation

Tags: android, android-cardview, stackview

I tried to develop an app with stack like this:

[image]

You can see that is the album widget of xperia or some other phone I suppose. The thing here is I try to implement this into an application of mine, which need to show the film poster in this way.

I tried using stackview or many other project that I could search but the result is not what I am expecting. Whenever I scroll down the view, the first one will be fade out and the second one will be the first one, and the other way, when I scroll up!